# Can't see ios .app package in Finder

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any chance to generate .app package with ios app from xCode without apple developer certificate? If yes, can this package be installed on real device?

Comment: You can side load apps now so you don't need an apple developer certificate. Although the app wont be on the apple app store and would be available through other means like android which has many stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate an app from finder as it is only created in Xcode at can only be installed in Xcode. An app cannot be distributed without a developer licence, developer certificate or a provisioning profile. To get these, you need to create a developer account which costs $99 per year. It's what is required if you want to test apps on iOS devices and not just the simulator. Here is the link to create an account: https://developer.apple.com/